# VueJS dynamically add textareas based on user click (tinymce issue)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I built a dynamic form where the user has the option to add as many HTML textareas as possible. The problem I'm running into is when the user loads the next textarea, I lose tinymce. Same thing happening for any external script (example: datepicker and Select2.js). Any ideas?

Here is my code

```
<div v-for="index in counter" :key="index">
      <email_template_row></email_template_row>
      <hr>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" @click="addRow" type="button">Add Row</button>
// Tinymce code here...
// load vuejs from cdn...
        Vue.component('email_template_row', {
            template: '<div><textarea name="col_2_content[]" class="form-control tinymce" placeholder="Body"></textarea></div>',
        });
        var vue = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data:{
              counter: 1
            },
            methods: {
                addRow: function () {
                    this.counter += 1;
                }
            },
        });
```

Thank you.

Comment: you should probably not be using outside libraries that manipulate the DOM with VueJS

Comment: Is there an alternative to tinymce, datepicker, select2js that will not manipulate the DOM with VueJS?

Comment: yes; there's tons of alternatives. this might be helpful https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: where is the tinymce?? where are datepicker and Select2.js???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-initialize those components after one is appended to the HTML.

So basically your `addRow` method should look like this:

```
addRow: function () {
    this.counter += 1;

    tinymce.init({
      selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML, you can be more specific
      auto_focus: 'element',
      // add your configuration
    });
}
```